# How to find latest non-merge commit message in Git?

Tags: git, bash

I'd like to find a last (newest) Git commit that is not a merge commit.

(Let's say we just check the commit message, and if it doesn't start with `Merge` then we assume commit is not a merge - is there some better way BTW?)

I've found this post that could be useful:

https://mislav.net/2010/07/git-tips/

```
Show the last commit which message matches a regex

$ git show :/fix
# shows the last commit which has the word "fix" in its message

$ git show :/^Merge
# shows the last merge commit
```

I can mix those attitudes to show last merge commit (this works well):

```
$ git show --format=%B ':/^(Merge)'
```

However the syntax for the regular expression here (starting with `:/`) is pretty obscure, not easy to find documentation for, and I don't understand how to invert it. When I try `?!` I get an error:

```
$ git show --format=%B ':/^(?!Merge)'
fatal: Invalid search pattern: ^(?!Merge)
```

Can someone guide me how to apply negative match with `git show`?

Note that the commit messages can be multiline.

Edit:

[image: gitk merges]

Let's consider a simple scenario, where all the merges could be fast-forwards (but are not). I want the commit marked in red to be found as "latest".

A script like this seems to do the trick but it's verbose

```
#!/bin/bash
readCommitMessage () {
    local commit="$1"
    lastCommitMsg=$(git log -1 --pretty=%B $commit)
    #echo "$lastCommitMsg"
}

commit="HEAD"
readCommitMessage
while [[ "$lastCommitMsg" == Merge* ]]; do
    commit="$commit""^2"
    readCommitMessage "$commit"
done

echo "$lastCommitMsg"
```

Comment: A merge commit is defined has having more than one parent -- so anything with less than 2 parent commits is not a merge commit. I don't know off the top of my head how to find out the number of a commit's parents, but it's probably not hard. Also, you should clearly define if by "latest/newest commit" you mean "newest by date" (if so, committer/author date?) or "latest on current branch" (by history graph)

Comment: I want latest by history graph starting from `HEAD`

Comment: As stated, this question is flawed, unless you mean "newest" commit in terms of the date it was committed or last-modified. If not, then say the most recent commit is a merge commit with two non-merge parents. Which parent would you consider to be the "newest" in that case?

Comment: I've done the edit to my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
git rev-list --no-merges -n 1 HEAD
```

You can also use `log` instead of `rev-list` if you want human readable output rather than just the sha1 which is likely to be more useful when scripting.

(You may want to use `--date-order` if you want the latest by date rather than just 'a' latest by topological order.)

Comment: Yeah this seems to work for me: `git show --format=%B $(git rev-list --no-merges -n 1 HEAD)`, thanks!

Comment: @jakub.g: Or just use `git log --format=%B --no-merges -n 1`.

Comment: Thanks. Aside, can you point me to some documentation about the regex syntax passed to `git show` that I presented? It seems non-standard to me. What does the leading semicolon mean for instance?

Comment: @jakub.g: `git help rev-parse` ?

Answer (score 2):

The following command is not as good as the top answer, but shorter for quick use.

```
git log --no-merges -1
```